# When does ID get generated in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

What I want to know is when `NHibernate` assigns/generates a value to Id field. After an entity is saved into repository? I need to use a Product `Id` to build a compound filename. But when I do use an `Id` before saving entity into repository I get `Guid.Empty`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am wondering why you need to use the `Id` before a save takes place? Surely using an `Id` after it has been successfully committed to the database is the correct approach. After all if  you use the `Id` and then find the database has not persisted the entity then this will give you unwanted side effects.

However there is a work around but it is not very nice.

Set the `id` generator to assigned. This comes with some caveats, you cannot use `SaveOrUpdate` as NHibernate will not be able to detect that this is a new entity or one that needs updating. This means that you should either use the `Save` or `Update` methods explicitly

Comment: I'm asking because I need to populate the entity properties - paths to images combined with entity's `Id` - before saving an entity. So it appears that I must make not a full write. Then save entity. Make another write operation when I can use `Id`. Make `Update`. Right?

Comment: Good valid point, however maybe you can combine the path and Id columns in the `select` statement using a computed/combined column rather than inserting the path into the table in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

please see below link for your answer

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id

***"But when I do use an Id before saving entity into repository I get Guid.Empty"***
 -> id will only be generated once record it saved into database... if you want id before then i would suggest using **assigned**
id generator, where you can generate your id before your record in saved into db.